# Галерея - позиция первого блока

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

У меня есть слайдер из 14 элементов. Необходимо под слайдером в строчку - 4 блока с надписями: первая, вторая, третья, четвёртая. С этим я справился. Я хочу, чтобы в зависимости от того, из какой группы блок, её название выделялось рамкой

- первые пять блоков в первой группе,
- четыре следующих во второй
- три следующих в третьей
- два последних в четвёртой

и

```
<div class="jMyCarousel">
<ul>
  <li class="1"><div class="news-text"><p>!1!Text</p></div></li>       
  <li class="1"><div class="news-text"><p>!2!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="1"><div class="news-text"><p>!3!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="1"><div class="news-text"><p>!4!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="1"><div class="news-text"><p>!5!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="2"><div class="news-text"><p>!6!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="2"><div class="news-text"><p>!7!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="2"><div class="news-text"><p>!8!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="2"><div class="news-text"><p>!9!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="3"><div class="news-text"><p>!10!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="3"><div class="news-text"><p>!11!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="3"><div class="news-text"><p>!12!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="4"><div class="news-text"><p>!13!Text</p></div></li>
  <li class="4"><div class="news-text"><p>!14!Text</p></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="buttom_block">
  <ul>
    <li> 1_блок  </li>
    <li> 2_блок  </li>
    <li> 3_блок  </li>
    <li> 4_блок  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Вопрос в том, как узнать 1-й элемент в блоке. Я хочу сравнивать первый элемент: если он равен `<li class="1">`, то высвечивать первый блок. Помогите найти позицию первого элемента.

Весь код программы можно скачать [здесь](http://webfile.ru/5607230). Пароль 1234.

Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ребята, HTML - это не язык програмирования, а язык гипертекстовой разметки, т.е. является статическим СИНТАКСИСОМ данной веб-страницы. И о динамическом изменении не может быть и речи. Для этих целей и создан javascript, VB и т.д. ПХП позволяет делать красоту с html-кодом, но увы требует обращения к серверу, т.е. обновлять страницу, посылаю НОВЫЙ html-код. поэтому без ява-скрипта не обойтись

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы при добавлении элементов в блок не приходилось лезть в js код, а можно было редактировать только html код? Например, к первому блоку относятся 5 элементов, ну чтобы можно было добавить еще пару элементов к этому блоку и в html указывать, к какому именно.

Comment: Я сделал для 14 элементов, ну мне нужно сделать для произвольного числа